# Simulate server failure with httptest or http package

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

How to simulate server failure with httptest or http package in isolated unit test?

**Details:**

I've been using gorilla websockets, so on `mt, msg, err := t.conn.ReadMessage()` *mt* value must be *-1* when server goes down.
I tried the following as the main option:

```
var srv *httptest.Server

srv = httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   _, err := wsUpgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
   if err != nil {
      t.Fatal(err)
   }

   srv.Close()
}))
```

But client didn't receive any messages at all. Also I had tried standard http server with panic, however after recover() client didn't receive any messages as well. `srv.CloseClientConnections()` didn't help, client waited for messages as before.

Comment: There is no `-1` message type. Why must `ReadMessage` return `-1`?

Comment: Also, if the server actually failed, there can't be any message; but in either case you should be checking for errors using the error value, not the message type.

Comment: @JimB In case of `wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` error `ReadMessage` returns `-1` as message type. Probably, this is not a good idea to use this value because it's not described in RFC, so could you please advise how to check forcibly closed connection by error value?

Comment: Without comparing `err.Error()` and whole `wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` string

Comment: What is the actual goal of your test? You seem to be testing an implementation detail of the gorilla package, not your code. If there is a server error you should expect an error, but there's any number of possible error conditions. If you're testing an error path, then check it with an error, but don't rely on a specific error.

Comment: The actual goal of my test is: to check how my custom WS client (built with gorilla package) reconnects to server in case of unexpected connection closing (in this case `wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.` representation of error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sufficient to call `conn.Close()` on client connection on WS server side in order to terminate connection without sending the close frame. This will trigger behavior with abnormal connection close and value of message type will be `-1`.

After connection upgrade to websocket it's hijacked and general http server cannot handle this connection anymore, that's why server closing doesn't work for hijacked connections.